# How to parse date time with offset Time (+05:30) into LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

Below expression is not working. I want to convert `2020-05-05T01:01:01.000+05:30` into `2020-05-05T01:01:01`. But before that I need to parse it into LocalDateTime. The problem is with the part "+00:00", not sure how to format it.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-05T01:01:01.000+05:30", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+00:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is date/time string with offset of plus 5 hours and 30 minutes from UTC, so just parse it directly into [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)

```
String dateTimeString = "2020-05-05T01:01:01.000+05:30";

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
```

And then get the LocalDateTime from it

```
offsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime();  //2020-05-05T01:01:01
```

Comment: This is not throwing exceptions as such but I'm facing the issue because of timezone differences. For some dates I'm getting T01:01 and T06:31 for others. IS there any way where we can have a consistent results using timezone. Like we add timezone for DateTimeFormatter